# PayPal & ASP.Net | DNN | Issue passing|setting value from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, paypal, dotnetnuke

How Can I pass the value for the amount into this code supplied by paypal so that it will function?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<input type="hidden" id="__TRANSACTIONID" runat="server" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="Server" ID="pnlDetails"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<input type="hidden" id="__Amount" runat="server" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    //SetAmount(Calculate_Amount()); // Also tried <% ClientID %>.val and few others
    //var PayPal_AMOUNT = __Amount.value;  //SCOPE CREEP // Lots of things deleted I have tried already

    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: 267.58 // HOW CAN I SET THIS VALUE PROPERLY?
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                alert('An Appointment was Booked and Scheduled by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                window.location.href = 'THEURL/Default.aspx';//?ID=' + __TRANSACTIONID.value;  //** SAME ISSUE IMPEEDING SETTING THIS VALUE...
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');

});
```

So I have tried many differnt approaches to get the data from the server to this code.  And I have tried adding it as a page script from code behind and it was not rendering...  This code is being installed as a DNN Module and rendered from IIS if that helps,

I have spent a few weeks comipiling and testing everything but a working method.  I am bashing my brain into the keyboard and it still does not compute.

I have tried the SDK, also but was throwing me more issues, thought just resolving this issue on how properly set these variables then it would work properly.

I appreciate your time, and wisdom if you could help!

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/  ---  CODE IN QUESTION

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/issues/12

Comment: If the first few lines that you're showing here are the same as your real code, that's a problem. Those inputs need to be rendered outside of the script tag.

Comment: That was an error in composing this post.  wanted to include the elements in use.

Comment: update_client_config_error {err: "Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status: 400 (C…2mBAUJ6aEWQuMLL1FSd5aG9da7FN&currency=EUR:1:78760", timestamp: "1580371041493", referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", buttonSessionID: "9f218c9fd8_mdc6ntc6mty", sessionID: "2c23a5489e_mdc6mzg6nti", …}

Comment: Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status: 400 (Corr ID: ea3b0e1872bbe)
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.cou